# How does the following derivative work?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

In the paper:

```
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0278364914558129?casa_token=d355ZLeI3zEAAAAA:gNiS1aqxfrnLOoRinjoPZoE8G21AyOlH6lBFZSjWoos3DTPcYNZIw92kC1bYNoWm9N2EWKMU2zo2zQ
```

[image]

on page $97$, the derivative of $(16)$ is $(17)$. 
 I don't understand how the derivative was taken. Was it taken with respect to $t$? If so, can you explain more thoroughly how the result was reached at?

Comment: As Andrei answered, you find the gradient of $J$ w.r.t. $b_P$. So, $\frac{\partial J}{\partial b_P} = R^T_{FP} b_F + R_{PF}b_F + \left(R_{PP} + R_{PP}^T\right)^T b_P = 0$. Assuming $R_{PP}$ is symmetric, i.e, $R_{PP} = R_{PP}^T$. Also, $R_{PF} = R^T_{FP}$  then $\frac{\partial  J}{\partial  b_P} = 2R^T_{FP} b_F + 2R_{PP}b_P = 0$ results (17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they differentiate $J$ with respect to $b_P$. $$\frac{\partial J}{\partial b_P}=2b_F^TR_{FP}+2b_P^TR_{PP}=0$$
From here $$b_P^TR_{PP}=-b_F^TR_{FP}$$
Transposing both sides yields
$$R_{PP}^Tb_p=-R_{FP}^Tb_F$$
Assuming $R_{PP}^T=R_{PP}$ is invertible, multiply on the left side with $R_{PP}^{-1}$ and you get the answer.

Comment: Why is R_pp invertible? And how come for any vector v, d v^T/dv = 0? Of course the transpose is dependent on the original vector, so why is the transpose's derivative to the original vector equal to 0 (which is why the terms containing b_p^T vanish to 0)?

Comment: I don't know if $R_{PP}$ is invertible. I assume that there are more details in the document. From a quick scan of it, it looks like a rotation matrix. For the other question, I forgot to put a factor of $2$ for both terms. See the comment to your question from @user550103. A quick way to understand it is to assume that you can switch the order of derivation and transposition. So $$\frac d{dx} x^TBy=\frac d{dx} (y^TB^Tx)^T=(y^TB^T\frac{dx}{dx})^T=By$$